# iphone - perform segue from custom TableCellView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView in which I am populating custom built UITableViewCells. These have a picture and a few labels.

Is there any way that when  click on the picture that it performs a certain segue but when I click on each of the labels it performs different segues. I only want these segues performed when I click on the UIImageView or the UILabels.

I am currently playing with the following idea.

1. Add gesture recogniser to UIImageView and UILables when creating them in cellForRowAtIndexPath
2. The above touch gesture will trigger the segue

My code looks like this in the UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate where I create my UITableViewCells

```
    cell.myImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTap.delegate = self;
    [cell.myImage addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

This overrides the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate for the table view when I click on the UIImageView so I've tried triggering the segue from the doSomething: function but this function doesn't know the UITableView indexPath so cannot send the right information to the destination viewcontroller (it always sends 0).

I'm sure there must be an easy away to do this

Any ideas welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `NSIndexPath` of cell `myImage` belongs to by adding following to tap handler `doSomething:`

```
- (void)doSomething:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
       CGPoint touch = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];

       NSLog(@"indexPath: %@", indexPath);

     //Select cell and trigger didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

      [self.myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
      [self tableView:self.myTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I add this code? The method triggered by singleTap doesn't have an event identifier defined so UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; fails.

Comment: Wow, That's great, thanks!! my doSomething method now has the indexPath of the selected tableCell. Is there any way for me to pass this to the prepareForSegue method or programmatically trigger the didSelectRowAtIndexPath so that the segue gets executed with the correct indexPath?

Comment: thanks so much for your help, I have updated your answer with two extra rows that show how to trigger the didSelectRowAtIndexPath methof from the doSomething method.

Answer (score 0):

UIGestureRecognizers have a view property you can access. Iterate over that view's superviews until you have the UITableViewCell and call:

```
[tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

that should give you the IndexPath.